# Sharepoint Foundation: how to create a webpart page with the standard page menu?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm a complete Sharepoint novice but got stuck with customizing Sharepoint. I'm trying to create a web part page, but that will have the standard left-side menu as a standard non-web part page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Open the site in SharePoint desginer and then desgin your newly added webpart page as per your requirment [Page Editing](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/04/sharepoint-designer-article-1-how-to.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it. How can I set this edited page as a default selection for when the user creates a web part page? Better, how can I just add the menu to all the web part page templates?

Comment: This doesn't work -- I can't add web parts. That feature is disabled.

Comment: You would have to add webpart on all pages. For second part its strange to hear that can you confirm if you have detached it from page layout

Comment: I'm not sure why people are saying this is an answer. Some better googling on my part reveals this is a known problem with workarounds to the master page. Unfortunately these don't work. I can't modify the part of the page that hides the menu in Sharepoint Designer--it's read only. Your soultion does not work.

Comment: I assume you are using SPD2010 in this case you have to use advanced mode for editing the Page HTML. Advanced mode is available in Home Ribbion when you open the page for editing

Comment: Left navigation menu comes from the master-page in normal scenario.plz confirm if your master page contains code for left navigation and as well none of the content place holders related to Left navigation are implemented in your content page(web part page).